# Добавление входящего параметра string и его передача

Tags: c#, сокет, byte

```
class Test
{
    static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
    static private string guid = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

public void WS_Thread_Start()
{
    Thread wsServer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WS_Start))
    {
        IsBackground = true
    };
    wsServer.Start();
}

private void WS_Start()
{
    serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 7777));
    serverSocket.Listen(128);
    serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
}

private static void OnAccept(IAsyncResult result)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    try
    {
        Socket client = null;
        string headerResponse = "";
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            client = serverSocket.EndAccept(result);
            var i = client.Receive(buffer);
            headerResponse = (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)).Substring(0, i);
        }
        if (client != null)
        {
            var key = headerResponse.Replace("ey:", "`").Split('`')[1].Replace("\r", "").Split('\n')[0].Trim();
            var test1 = AcceptKey(ref key);
            var newLine = "\r\n";
            var response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols" + newLine
                 + "Upgrade: websocket" + newLine
                 + "Connection: Upgrade" + newLine 
                 + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + test1 + newLine + newLine;
            client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
            var i = client.Receive(buffer);
            var subA = SubArray<byte>(buffer, 0, i);
            client.Send(subA);
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException exception)
    {
        Utils.Logging(Utils.Type.DEBUG, exception.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (serverSocket != null && serverSocket.IsBound)
        {
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(null, 0, OnAccept, null);
        }
    }
}

public static T[] SubArray<T>(T[] data, int index, int length)
{
    T[] result = new T[length];
    Array.Copy(data, index, result, 0, length);
    return result;
}

private static string AcceptKey(ref string key)
{
    string longKey = key + guid;
    byte[] hashBytes = ComputeHash(longKey);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
}

static SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
private static byte[] ComputeHash(string str)
{
    return sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
}
```

}

Суть проблемы, есть фрагмент кода который работает и принимает сообщение от клиента и это же самое сообщение передает назад. Хотелось бы реализовать возможность отправки сообщений не в режиме попугая. А скажем вызывается класс Test с параметром string и этот же string уже передается клиенту.

```
Test("сообщение");
```

Comment: Какие с этим сложности?

Comment: Если бы не было сложностей не писал бы :) Есть идеи? Подсказывайте. Не соображу как и что сделать.

Comment: Вы выкатили кусок кода и написали, что хотите сделать. Но тут не сервис по написанию кода, тут помогают решать проблемы. То есть если вы что то пытались, но у вас не получается -  добавьте это в вопрос. А пока ваш вопрос больше похож на техзадание, чем на вопрос, потому вам никто и не ответил.

Comment: tym32167, я спрашиваю совет как и где, что то поправить, потому как у самого мало опыта в этой области.

Comment: `Test("сообщение");` - это не вызов класса, это вызов метода. Просто вынесите кусок кода, который внутри `if`, в отдельный метод (или класс).

Comment: Alexander, благодарю за то, что уделили время, но я не совсем понимаю в какой момент 
`if (client != null)` 
необходимо вставить свои данные ибо как я понимаю оно все передается в byte.

Comment: Насколько я понял 

`client.Send(subA);` 

 отвечает за отправку сообщений, но тогда вопрос как правильно перевести сообщение в 

`byte`

 ?

Comment: вот же перевод в байты и отправка `client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));`

Comment: Вопрос каким образом передать свой 
`response`
вот это и не совсем понятно. Данные полченные от клиента он передает на ура, аж с песней!

Comment: при попытке передать свое или ошибка сокета или просто не отправляет